# ul vertical align in bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

According to Bootstrap4 document, we can use predefined class `align-items-center` and `justify-content-center`to make contents vertically and horizontally aligned. I test Bootstrap4 document example and it works as it should be, but in using `align-items-center` and `justify-content-center` classes in the following code it's not desirable! I make `ul` tag `display:flex` using bootstrap classes but it's contents (`li tags`) are not aligned horizontally and vertically centered. Also I checked `ul` property in `inspects` of Chrome and it has `margin-top: 0` and `margin-bottom: value`. What is the problem?

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="top-ribbon" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div id="socials" class="col-6 col-md-2 offset-md-2">
                    <ul class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                        <li class="list-inline-item color-white"><i">1</i></li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item color-white">2<i"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Css:

```
color-white{
    color: white;
}
#top-ribbon{
    background-color: rgb(168, 8, 133);
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 200px;
}
.row{
  height: 200px;
}
#top-ribbon div{
    border: 1px solid;
}
#socials ul{
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxofsr68/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, you have issues with your HTML syntax. Second, you need to realize that there is a default padding and margin on `ul` elements in bootstrap. Remove those and you get the desired effect.

```
#socials ul {
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xxofsr68/3/

I made two examples for you to look at.

Comment: Thanks, "first, you have issues with your HTML syntax" what do you mean?

Comment: @soheil Sorry for the late reply. Your HTML tags were like this: `<i">` it should be just `<i>`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Add the Universal Class i.e. *{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
It remove the extra space.
For Vertically align add display:flex; and align-flex:center;
In the program margin-bottom added, so it should be margin-bottom:0px;

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.color-white {
  color: white;
}

#top-ribbon {
  background-color: rgb(168, 8, 133);
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  Width:100%;float:left;
}

.row {
  height: 300px;
}

#top-ribbon div {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
}

#socials {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

#socials ul {
 
  margin-bottom: 0px;

  width: 100%;
  float:left;text-align:center;
}

#socials ul li{float:left;}
```

```html
<div id="top-ribbon" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <div id="socials" class="col-6 col-md-2 offset-md-2">
      <ul class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <li class="list-inline-item color-white">1</li>
        <li class="list-inline-item color-white">2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer